# Error 404 Scrapy on Python url to be scraped works (sometimes) in browser but not in python

Tags: python, scrapy, http-status-code-404

I'm working on a project where the data of the following url needs to be scraped: https://www.funda.nl/objectinsights/getdata/5628496/

The last part of the url represents the ID of an object. Opening the link in the browser does work, but sometimes it returns a 404 error. The same when using scrapy shell in python, sometimes I can scrape the url, sometimes not.

When I managed to open the url(without 404 error), I went to inspect > network. But i'm not experienced enough to understand this information. Does someone know the fix? Or additional information to this topic?

Extra urls you can try:

```
https://www.funda.nl/objectinsights/getdata/5819260/
https://www.funda.nl/objectinsights/getdata/5819578/
https://www.funda.nl/objectinsights/getdata/5819237/
https://www.funda.nl/objectinsights/getdata/5819359/
https://www.funda.nl/objectinsights/getdata/5819371/
https://www.funda.nl/objectinsights/getdata/5819386/
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested these in scrapy shell and got response 200 each time.

This is not a Scrapy issue if you are having intermittent 404 response even from browser.

They may well limiting you to a small number of requests per ip address or per minute.

Try write some code with a delay in it between requests, or use rotating proxy (free trials are out there if you don't want t sign up for one).